# Boost.Thread timed wait

Tags: c++, windows, boost, boost-thread

What happens to thread run under Windows OS, when the timeout occurs using `boost::thread::timed_join`, and the waiting thread finishes? Does the thread remain or it finishes along with the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter why a thread finishes (exits), what matters is whether this is the main thread or not: if it's the main thread, then the whole process exits, and all its threads get terminated; if it's a non-main thread, its graceful exit doesn't affect any other threads.

[The following article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686722%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) explains a process termination in detail.

Comment: The main thread waits for other one it started. Are you absolutely sure the thread does not remain in OS and releases its resources?

Comment: @MarcAndreson please note that you mix 2 different questions: 1) whether process' threads get closed on process exit; 2) whether all process resources get freed on process exit. Please, see the following link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686722(v=vs.85).aspx